# Pandas Filtering row based on value using column index

Tags: pandas

I am trying to filter a Dataframe based on value in a column

```
cust_id, prod_type
101, prod_A
102, prod_A
102, prod_B
103, prod_F
103, prod_A
104, prod_D
```

I am trying to filter based on column index as below:

```
df.loc[df.columns[1].eq('prod_A')]
```

It throws an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'eq'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select second column by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1].eq('prod_A')]
```

Your solution should be changed with `df[]`, because `df.columns[1]` return column name:

```
df.loc[df[df.columns[1]].eq('prod_A')]
```